# How can I show that $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ goes to 0 exponentially fast as n goes to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I show that $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ approaches $0$ exponentially fast as $n$ approaches infinity?

I have never heard of "Exponentially fast to 0".

Do I have to compare this sequence with some exponent sequence?

Comment: That's more or less the definition of "exponentially fast" ($r^n$ for $|r|<1$).

Comment: $(2/3)^n$ is an exponential function.  If $c=\log_e 3 - \log_e 2 \approx 0.405465$  then $(2/3)^n = \exp(-cn)$

Comment: might be they mean "faster than any polynomial", i.e. for a polynomial $p$ holds that $\frac{\frac{2}{3}^n}{p\left(n\right)}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Do you mean to ask what "exponentially fast" means? If that's the case, this could be made much clearer.

Comment: yeah, and How can I show that (2/3)^n goes to 0 exponentially fast

Comment: by defining what that means first^^

Answer (score 0):

Exponentially fast means that its rate of speed is proportional to its current value.  In other words, f'(x) = c*f(x).

So f(x) = $\frac{2}{3}^x$ so f'(x) = $\lim \frac{(2/3)^{x + h} - (2/3)^x}{h} = \lim \frac{(2/3)^x((2/3)^h -1)}{h} = (2/3)^x \lim \frac{((2/3)^h -1}{h}$ = ln(2/3)*f(x).

Basically "exponentially fast" means as fast as an exponent so...